# Earliest Sources To Avoid Pronouncing the Name 'Samael'

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, speech-talking, malach-angel, superstition

What are the earliest explicit sources that reference the practice of not pronouncing the name ['Samael'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samael)?

I ask since I have heard many people doing this. It is referenced here: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/?q=%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9C&search_in=0

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/saying-names-of-angels?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rav [Shmuel Vital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Vital) (17th century) in the [siddur חמדת ישראל](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53884&st=&pgnum=221) says this.

> גם צריך להזהר מאד שלא להזכיר בפיו שם סמא"ל וזהו סוד מש"ה אלהים אחרים לא תזכירו וכו' ובפרט בלילה שאז היא שליטתו וממשלתו.ולא עוד אלא שגם הוא אסור להזכיר מעין דברים אלו כגון בני אדם הרגילים לומר בלשון לע"ז איל דייאבל"ו וכיוצא בדברים אלו אין להזכירם כלל לפי שגם השדי"ם הם בחלקו ומגביר כוחו כשיזכיר אותם. ופעם אחת הייתי עם בני אדם בלילה והזכרתי באמצע הדיבור שהייתי עמהם את שם סמא"ל ואח"כ בבקר הלכתי לבית מורי ז"ל ונסתכל בי ואמר לי הרי בלילה הזאת עברת על לאו ושם  אלהים אחרים לא תזכירו. ולכן הזהר כל ימיך שלא תזכירו לא את שמו ולא כיוצא בו ובפרט בלילה כי אז ניתן לו כח להתגבר עליך ועל אחרים בסיבתך אם תזכי שמו ולכן ראוי להזכירו בשם אחד טוב כמו סמ"ך מ"ם וכיוצא מאלו השמות שיש בהם מקצת קדושה כל זה לשון אזהרת מורי זלה"ה

I don't know if this is the earliest source, but it *seems* like it would be.