# Napoleon Bonaparte was a shin daled?

Tags: chabad, chassidic-rebbe

I heard that the Alter Rebbe wrote in the Tanya that the French emperor Napoleon Bonaparte was a shin daled. Does someone know if it’s true, and where is it written?

*Btw It’s famous that the Alter Rebbe was an opponent of Napoleon’s ideas…*

Comment: Considering the Tanya was first published in 1796, when Napoleon wasn't even the ruler of France yet, it certainly wouldn't be in there.

Comment: For anyone trying to understand what a "shin daled" is, [see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/am-i-allowed-to-use-the-word-sheid-demon)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard that Napoleon was a *shin daled*, and he's definitely not mentioned in Tanya, but there's a legend that the Alter Rebbe considered him a sorcerer. See [here](https://heichalhanegina.blogspot.com/2007/01/rav-baal-hatanya-and-napoleons-march.html):

> With the assistance of the Russian army, the Rebbe and his entire family began their flight, loaded on four wagons, on Erev Shabbos, 22 Av, 5572 (1812). Before leaving, he instructed the townspeople to help themselves to his furniture and utensils and to make sure to remove everything that was in his house. After traveling approximately two miles, the Alter Rebbe asked the commander for a fast carriage and horses. Together with two attendants, he returned to Liadi and instructed them to search the house for anything that might have been left behind. After a thorough search, they found a pair of worn-out slippers, a sieve, and a rolling pin in the attic. Not wanting Napoleon to obtain any memorabilia from him, the Alter Rebbe took these objects with him. Chassidim insist that the Alter Rebbe thought that Napoleon was a sorcerer, and if he would have gotten hold of anything that belonged to the Alter Rebbe, he would have used it to guarantee his victory (or in the least, to mitigate against the Alter Rebbe's ability to oppose him). Then he told his attendants to set fire to the house, and they left.
>
> This was not a second too early, as immediately afterwards, Napoleon's soldiers entered the city from the opposite direction. Despite their utmost efforts, they were unsuccessful in putting out the fire. All that was left of the Rebbe's house were smoldering ashes. In Napoleon's name, the French soldiers proclaimed that anyone who would give them something that had belonged to the Alter Rebbe would be richly rewarded with gold coins. Obeying the Alter Rebbe's wishes, no one gave them anything. In their anger, the French soldiers burned down the shul that was adjacent to the Alter Rebbe's former house. The Alter Rebbe had foreseen this, and before leaving had instructed the townspeople of Liadi to remove everything from the shul before Napoleon's arrival there.

Comment: yes this is a very famous story

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer the question directly but Napoleon was primarily good for Jews in that he continued the emancipation of Jews which gave them citizenship in France and in Concord French territories emancipated Jews. He removed laws that required them to live in ghettos. He had assimilationist beliefs but that was not something he had only to Jews. They were free to join military service completely equal to any other group. Ironically, had Napoleon not lived, there never would have been a Dreyfus affair years after his death because a Jew like Dreyfus who attained the high rank of Captain in the French army never would have been able to attain such a level of service as a Jew but for Napoleon's egalitarian beliefs. Napoleon also revolutionized Europe in many ways which affected Jews. He created the French civil service which became a model for civil service throughout Europe and the world where people join a government entity and raise to the level of their merit. This was a general belief that enabled all people to realize the potential and in as much as Jews could not do that in countries where they were excluded from various practice one way or the other, his commitment to believing that a country is most effective when it runs on merit is something that helped the Jews to a large degree. Before this era, Jews were largely forbidden in many countries to own land or to participate in many businesses or guilts. This is why many Jews became money lenders and bankers and Napoleon did try to and the practice of Jews as money lenders. Whatever his motive, it's clear that he did not like individual groups to live in their own niches.  He had no problem with religious practices and under his ring Judaism was recognized as an official religion within france. No Jew had fear under the authority of Napoleon for being Jewish as they had had in France before the revolution and in many other countries throughout Europe.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Alan and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Welcome Alan! Are you suggesting the he definitely wasn't a shin daled because he was good to us?  If so, I suggest that you edit your answer to clarify.  I'd also suggest that that may need a little justification as I wouldn't know for sure that shin daleds aren't good to Jews

Comment: the reason why the alter rebbe opposed Napoleon is that he wanted to favor the material of the Jews while wanting to control the spirituality of the Jews in order to make them more and more secular, so he favored spiritual comfort to the material and therefore opposed Napoleon

Comment: @MosesSupposes eg, Ben Tamalyon